# Add search functionality in asp.net mvc using ADO.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm new in asp.net MVC and I want to add search functionality by date to my app.(I'm using ado.net)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write a stored procedure in sql server which can accept date as parameter
2. In ado.net, you can you execute datareader, call this stored procedure and pass the parameter value.